# Returning HTTP status 204 for GET /generate_204 using uhttpd?

Tags: php, cgi, openwrt, lua

To deal with the Android captive portal detection for my specific setup, I need to return an HTTP status code 204 whenever I get a GET request for `/generate_204`. I currently use uhttpd as my webserver, so I'm wondering whether this is possible to do with this server.

My current understanding: I need to write myself a CGI (or PHP or Lua) script that returns something like
 `Status: 204 No Result`

The question I have is how I can configure uhttpd to forward requests to `/generate_204` to CGI or PHP or Lua, since that neither has a prefix nor a file-extension that I can match for this purpose.

Comment: Use something along the lines `option lua_prefix       /generate_204` and have your script as the index document in that subdirectory?

Comment: @HBruijn That seems like a good idea. I tried it and if I open the `/generate_204` url, it does give me the desired result, but it changes the url in the browser window to `/generate_204/` (notice the xtra slash at the end). The Android captive portal detection still fails. Looking at the source code, it uses a request with `FollowRedirects` set to `false`. Is uhttp generating a redirect to `/generate_204/` when I make the request? Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately @HBruijn's quite clever idea of simply making `/generate_204` a directory rather than a file and then using that as the `cgi_prefix` with an `index.cgi`-file inside it as the `index_page`, only works partly. When I open `/generate_204` from the browser myself, it does exactly what I wanted, but only after first returning a redirect to `/generate_204/`, which the Android captive portal detection explicitly ignores. So, unfortunately this solution doesn't solve my problem.

Here's the hack-job I've come up with that does seem to work:

Simply don't have a `/generate_204` file at all and instead create a CGI-script in `cgi-bin` that handles all erroneous requests that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$REQUEST_URI" == "/generate_204" ]; then
    echo "Status: 204 No Content"
    echo ""
    exit
fi

echo "Status: 404 Not Found"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo ""
cat /path/to/my/error404.html
```

Then simply add the following to `/etc/config/uhttpd`:

```
option error_page  /cgi-bin/error.cgi
option cgi_prefix  /cgi-bin
list   interpreter ".cgi=/bin/ash"
```

(adjusting file and folder names as needed)

This is definitely not the cleanest solution, and in case there's a way to prevent the redirect and make @HBruijn's idea work, I'll leave the question open for now, since I'd much prefer that.